# Searching through map using user input does not work

Tags: scala, list, search

This is what I need;

The user inputs a key value and a number; For instance "SK1 > 34"

The system then uses the key value from this to search through a map list called "mapdata". This is a "Map(String, List[Int])"

This value is returned with only the last digit.

However the problem I have is that when the system uses the key value to search the map, it fails to find it, even though the key value inputted is in the map.

If I change the user stackCost to direct entering "SK1" then it works. This shows me the problem is in finding "stockValue" even though my test shows it is searching for SK1.

Here is my current code;

```
def addNewStock =
  {
    println("Enter stock as *SK1* > AMOUNT(8) and the stock level will be taken from the stocks*")
    print("Enter new Stock > ")
    val key = readLine()
    var result = key.split(";").map(_ split ">") collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) } toMap

    println ("Data entered into file " + result)
    //String.valueOf(
    var stockValue = String.valueOf(result.head._1)
    var stockCost = mapdata.get(stockValue)

    println("This is the stock value " + stockValue)
    println("This is the stock cost " + stockCost)

  }
```

mapdata that is being queried;

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
SK6, 2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9
SK7, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0
SK8, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6
SK9, 7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6
```

EDITS***

```
var testing = result.toList
var stockValue = String.valueOf(result.head._1)
var stockCost = mapdata.get(stockValue).toList
var stockCheck = stockCost.map(_.lastOption.getOrElse(0))
var result2 = testing ::: stockCheck
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Please add a comment if you downvote

Comment: Did you enter that example string exactly as in the question: "SK1 > 34". Because that string contains spaces, so your stockValue would be "SK1 " not "SK1".

Comment: "hough the key value inputted is in the map." So this is clearly not the case. So mapValues doesn't contain what you think. Show the code that generates it.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul if i directly search for "SK1" instead of using the "SK1" pulled from the user input it finds it

Comment: Then the '"SK1" pulled from the user input' isn't what you think it is (as @vikram-r says, it might have a space, for example).. There's nothing different about the characters S, K and 1 just because the user typed them.  When you're assuming your problem is the standard Scala collection `Map` is not working, that should cause you to stop and re-consider. It's possible - but overwhelmingly more likely that the problem is how you are using it.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I 100% think you are right and it is the way I am using it, in my tests it appears that when I pull "SK1" from the user input thats all there is, how can i test this further? All ive done is check with println's. I am a student and still learning, all help appreciated

Comment: Print out the stockValue surrounded by quotes to see what you really have. `println("This is the stock value \"" + stockValue+"\"")`, for example. Or discover how to step through  your code with a debugger (this is a skill you will need in future anyway). And answer @vikram-r's question!

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Ive made a monumental mistake in misreading his question, That was exactly the problem! I have debugged in multiple other platforms and you are right, I do need to learn how to do it here. Thank you for your help

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Hey, while ive got you, i have the result "List((SK4,12), 8)"  how would I modify this to "List((SK4,12,8))"? I tried to use flatten but I got an error

Comment: You have a list of  a tuple and an integer? Bad idea. Lists should have elements all of the same type. Fix that, instead.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Thats what I thought, please view modified question

Comment: Since your modfied question neither says what's wrong or gives any details of what resulted, I can't do much. And anyway, a) I don't have time and b) if you have a different question now, add it as a separate question not as an addendum to your other one

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul I cannot post another question as I have not yet spent enough time using stackoverflow, can I edit this question completely as there are no answers?

Comment: @CornerShop It's very bad practice to completely change a question after you've created it. It would make this entire comment chain make no sense to any future viewiers. I added an answer to this question, and suggest that you post a new question when StackOverflow allows you to!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your test string. You are using the string `"SK1 > 34"` to test. When you call `split(">")` on this string, you will get back a `Array("SK1 ", " 34")`. Notice how there are spaces in both of those strings. This means that when you query `mapdata`, you are using the string `"SK1 "` (with a space at the end), which clearly is not a key in your map (because `"SK1 " != "SK1"`). A more appropriate test string for this use case would be `"SK1>34"`.